# sql server connection fail after the sql server is restarted

Tags: c#, sql-server, restart

i am doing a unit test against my project. in one case, i have to stop the sql server and verify if my application could handle such exception elegantly.

but i found the after this test case has run, any test case run after it would fail if the test case need to access the database. and the error was 'transportation level error'.

in each test case, i will setup a new sql connection and close it gracefully. i think the test cases are isolated very well. i do not understand why restarting the sql server would cause such error.

currently, i will have to hit the sql server myself after it is restarted. i think it is really an ugly fix.

Comment: Can you show your code for connecting to the sqlserver in each of the test?

Comment: So to be clear, you stop the SQL Server for one test case, restart it, wait a reasonable time for it to start(!) and then run the subsequent tests?

Comment: ZERO PERCENT acceptance is a major deterrent.

Comment: @RRUZ - I agree with you. @davidshen84, accept answers or you will find that nobody will want to support you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Restarting the SQL Server means that all connections get killed, including your application's (possibly pooled) connection. I think you just have to handle this error and retry. Which admittedly is a pain.

Comment: yeah, i guess it has some thing related to the sql connection pool. but i think after i have restarted the sql server, the connection pool should all be invalid, and sql server should not return me the pooled connection.